# Stylus error: "expected "indent", got "outdent", possibly because of invalid interpolation

Tags: css, stylus

Stylus code:

```
Sprite($positiveXCoordinate, $positiveYCoordinate, $width, $height)
  width {$width}px
  height {$height}px
  background-position -{$positiveXCoordinate}px -{$positiveYCoordinate}px
```

Error:

```
   157| Sprite($positiveXCoordinate, $positiveYCoordinate, $width, $height)
   158|   width {$width}px
   159|   height {$height}px
   160|   background-position -{$positiveXCoordinate}px -{$positiveYCoordinate}px
   161| 
--------^

expected "indent", got "outdent"
```

- If to remove above code from file, error will disappear.
- IDE automatically adding line to the end of file (but because of previous clause, it does not seems to be a cause)
- [Stylus online](https://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=Sprite(%24positiveXCoordinate%2C%20%24positiveYCoordinate%2C%20%24width%2C%20%24height)%0A%20%20width%20%7B%24width%7Dpx%0A%20%20height%20%7B%24height%7Dpx%0A%20%20background-position%20-%7B%24positiveXCoordinate%7Dpx%20-%7B%24positiveYCoordinate%7Dpx%0A%0A.TestClass%0A%20%20Sprite(2%2C%204%2C%206%2C%208)) does not not compiles it too.

I tried to find all spaces in file:

[image]

### Update: experiment

Works:

```
Sprite($positiveXCoordinate, $positiveYCoordinate, $width, $height)
  width 2px
```

Fails with `expected "indent", got "outdent"`:

```
Sprite($positiveXCoordinate, $positiveYCoordinate, $width, $height)
  width {$width}px
```

Looks line the interpolation is invalid, bit I did non found the example, how interpolate in cases like this.

Comment: the error message can be caused if you're mixing tabs and spaces for indentation.

Comment: @AliAli, thanks you for the comment. Maybe you right, but I has not not confirm it yet. I added the experiments results to question field.

Answer (score 0):

Not much info at the [official doc](https://stylus-lang.com/docs/interpolation.html)...can you try

```
Sprite($positiveXCoordinate, $positiveYCoordinate, $width, $height)
  width: $width * 1px
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of experiments, I make it works. And has been a little bit disappointed by Stylus.

```
Sprite($positiveXCoordinate, $positiveYCoordinate, $width, $height)
  width $width px
  height $height px
  background-position: -($positiveXCoordinate)px (-($positiveYCoordinate)px)
```

Here, colon requires after `background-position`. Also, if to remove outermost parenthesis from `(-($positiveYCoordinate)px)`, Stylus will compute `$positiveXCoordinate` and `$positiveYCoordinate` to single value.

Additional info:

- [About minus sign interpolation](https://github.com/stylus/stylus/issues/2160#issuecomment-204992147)